# Multiple Statement in single connection

Tags: java, sql-server

I wrote code to run multiple statement in single connection. The first statement will retrieve IDs to be looped and used by the second statement then get the desired output. As example:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT ID FROM __TestParent WHERE Status = 'S'";

    try (
        Connection conn = DbConnector.getConnection();
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        Statement s2 = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql1)
    ) {
            while(rs.next()) {
                String id = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ID"));
                String sql2 = "SELECT Description FROM __TestChild WHERE FK = " + id;
                try (
                    ResultSet rs2 = s2.executeQuery(sql2)
                ) {
                    while(rs2.next())
                        Util.printLog("INFO",rs2.getString("Description"));

                }catch(SQLTimeoutException sqltoex){
                    Util.printLog("SEVERE",sqltoex);
                }catch(SQLException sqlex){
                    Util.printLog("SEVERE",sqlex);
                }

            }

    }catch(SQLTimeoutException sqltoex){
        Util.printLog("SEVERE",sqltoex);
    }catch(SQLException sqlex){
        Util.printLog("SEVERE",sqlex);
    }
```

- Util.printLog method is to print the message in the desired format

The code run perfectly fine and the output was as expected. What I want to know is:

1. Is this the right way to do it, or is/are there better way to write the code.
2. Is there anything that I need to be aware of? Because I seems cannot find anything about this use case other than this link [Multiple-statements-single-connection from CodeRanch](https://coderanch.com/t/298352/databases/Multiple-statements-single-connection) which is 16-year-old thread and I'm not quite clear other than driver support.

Thanks.

Comment: Your second query should be parameterized. However, the single set-based statement in Tim Biegeleisen's answer will perform significantly better.

Comment: @DanGuzman as far as I know, parameterization is to avoid injection from user input. The ID variable is from the first query, which is not from user input, thus I'm not using any paramter. But I may wrong and love to learn more, please explain more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Parameterization has benefits other than security. Performance is improved by reusing query plans (avoiding compilation). Data is passed as native types so one doesn't need to format dates according to culture, specify culture-specific decimal separators, and escape quotes. The code is cleaner and easier to maintain too.

Comment: By reusing query plan, as as I know, it only benefit if we are using the same query but with different parameter value, I only query once, don't see any benefit on performance. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for the other input, that really interesting.

Comment: With SQL Server, consider that the query plan is cached on the server side. Subsequent executions can reuse the execution plan on the server side, avoiding compilation costs on subsequent executions. With a non-parameterized query, you can end up with many cached plans that differ only by literal values, wasting both memory and CPU time on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do what you want using a single query and result set:

```
SELECT c.Description
FROM __TestChild c
INNER JOIN __TestParent p
    ON c.FK = p.ID
WHERE p.Status = 'S';
```

Code:

```
String sql = "SELECT c.Description FROM __TestChild c ";
sql += " INNER JOIN __TestParent p ON c.FK = p.ID ";
sql += "WHERE p.Status = 'S'";

try (
    Connection conn = DbConnector.getConnection();
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql)
) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        Util.printLog("INFO", rs.getString("Description"));
    }
} catch(SQLTimeoutException sqltoex) {
    Util.printLog("SEVERE",sqltoex);
} catch(SQLException sqlex) {
    Util.printLog("SEVERE",sqlex);
}
```